# Sharepoint 2013 visited links not changing color

Tags: css, sharepoint-2013

I have a document list on Sharepoint 2013. I expect the color to change after clicking on an item in the list. (this is the behavior I used to get in Sharepoint 2010) however, the link color is not changing. Is this a bug in Sharepoint 2013 or I'm missing something?

Comment: You will need to post some code.

Comment: I'm using Sharepoint 2013 out of the box. Do you want me to post the html generated by sharepoint?

Comment: I think we need to see some css potentially, possibly html also. I would try and inspect it in the browser (I use chrome) you can simulate the hover state on any element and then check the corresponding css in the inspector. I don't know much about sharepoint, but inspecting in the browser will reveal the issue.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming this is a problem of just CSS (because you did tag it as a CSS issue), link colors can easily be manipulated.

There are four stages to a link:

- a:link
- a:visited
- a:active
- a:hover

You can use CSS to change the link colors (*for all of the links*) of each of these states by simply doing:

```
a:link { color:#FFF; }
a:visited { color:#000000; }
```

Now the links are seperate colors depending on if it were visited or not.

If you want to assign link colors to a **specific** div or id you can just replace a in the css for you div or id.

Example:

```
navigation:link {color: #FFF; }
navigation:visited { color: #000000; }
```